# Vim command to reset to the oldest change?

Tags: vim, editor, shortcut

I am a Vim user and sometimes I made several changes in a file but then want to get back to the beginning and have to type :u a lot of times, so I ask you if there is a shortcut to get to the "oldest change"?

Cheers!

Rodrigo Alves Vieira
http://rodrigo3n.com | @rodrigo3n

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The keystroke to undo is just <kbd>u</kbd>; if you're pressing <kbd>:</kbd><kbd>u</kbd> then that's too many keys (although it works, it's four keys instead of one). Usually I would just hold down <kbd>u</kbd> and let auto-repeat do the trick (note that `Ctrl+R` is the opposite of `u` if you go too far)..

You can reload from the last saved version on disk using `:e!`.

Comment: You can also supply a count to undo: `1000` `u`. Redo to most recent with `1000` `CTRL-R`.

Answer (score 5):

Does '`:e!`' (followed by <kbd>return</kbd>) work for you?  It gets back to the state of the edited file when it was last saved, or when you started if you've not saved yet...

Answer (score 4):

You also have the `:earlier` command. `:help :ea`

Comment: Interesting - I was not aware of `:earlier` (`:ea`) and `:later` (`:lat`) - thank you.

Comment: Also, you can use their shortenings `g-` and `g+`.

Answer (score 2):

Using `:e!` will get you back to the oldest change as saved. Aside from typing just `u` instead of `:u`, also see `:h undo-redo` for help on all the undo commands.

Other options might be use a vim plugin, such as [undo_tags](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1997).

Answer (score 1):

You know you can use repeat counts on just about any VIM command, right?

My favorite way:

10000u

ten-thousand-undos.

Zips me back in time, usually to where I opened the file.  I can see how things USED to be.

then

10000^R

then-thousand-redos

And I'm back at the end again.

You're welcome.